# PDF not creating pages. Whats wrong in this code in R?

Tags: r

Hello I am running a code that works out my ROC curve for my data,  I am using the following code.

However it producing the ROC PDF but with no graphs etc.

Any ideas where I have gone wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

```
DF <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.csv", all.files = T )
n <- length(fname)
lst <- vector("list", length=n)
test <- matrix(data = NA, nrow=n, ncol=1)
for(i in 1:n){
  cat("\n",i)
  data <- read.csv(fname[i], header=T)
  s <- summary(data)
  breath <- c(DF$Absolute.Neg.74, DF$Absolute.Pos.74)
  n=nrow(DF)
  out <-  c(rep(0,length=n),rep(1,length=n))
  DF1 <- data.frame(breath=breath, out=out)
  str(DF1)
  DF1 <- na.omit(DF1)
  fm<- glm(out~breath, data=DF1)
  summary(fm)
  resp <- predict(fm, newdata = DF1, type = "response")
  DF1$resp <- resp
  cutoff = 0.05
  pred <- resp >cutoff
  DF1$pred <- as.numeric(pred)
  table(DF1$out, DF1$pred)
  library(pROC)
  myroc <- roc(out~resp, data = DF1)
  myroc
  auc(myroc)
  plot.roc(myroc, main=paste0('ROC curve of breath: ' , names(data)[1]),         col = 'red')
 }

pdf(file="ROC.pdf")
opar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 1:n){
  cat("\n",i)
  data <- read.csv(fname[i], header=T)
  plot.roc(myroc, main=paste0('ROC curve of breath: ' , names(data)[1]),    col = 'red')
}

par(opar)
dev.off()
```

Comment: How is `plot.roc` defined? Is it based on grid graphics (such as ggplot2)? Then it should be wrapped in `print`.

Comment: Your code contains a lot of redundancies and inefficiencies. Also, the definition of the problem is imprecise and superficial, and you don't show any prior effort. Thus, you practically seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Thank you Roland. I will add that in.

Answer (score 0):

Just adapt this (much simpler) code:

```
data("iris")
library(pROC)

iris$y <- ifelse(iris$Species=="setosa",1,0)
roc.list <- list()
n <- 4
```

This gives you all the plots in separated files

```
for(i in 1:n){
     fit <- glm(y~Sepal.Length + Petal.Length, data=iris)
     roc.list[[i]] <- roc(y~Sepal.Length, data = iris)
     pdf(file = paste0("FileName",i,".pdf"))
     plot(roc.list[[i]])
     dev.off()
}
```

This gives you a 2X2 matrix of plots

```
pdf(file = paste0("File2Name.pdf"))
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(roc.list[[1]])
plot(roc.list[[2]])
plot(roc.list[[3]])
plot(roc.list[[4]])
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and comment.  I am not asking anyone to write code for me.  The code works that I wrote works well but the only problems was it was not adding any pages on the PDF.  So I was looking for advice as I couldn't find the error and have spent many hours looking for the answer. When people are learning it nice to ask people with more experience for help, not negativity.

Comment: There is no negativity, just constructive criticisms for your next questions.

Comment: Thank you for the simpler code.  I am looking at making changes at mine at the moment and your matrix of plots.  So hopefully it will work.

Comment: Consider that other solutions are possible of course. In case you want to use `ggplot2` you should check out the `multiplot()` function (this is also explained in the [R cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/)), `ggarrange()` from the `gpubr` package [see here](http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/ggpubr/reference/index.html#section-arrange-and-export-multiple-ggplots), or `grid.arrange()` from the `gridExtra` package.

Comment: Many thanks for the links and your help! I have not come across the cookbook before so looking through it now. Cheers.